# Winforms update DataGridView in another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, user-interface

Hello Gurus I have a DataGridView object in a Form. In a service class I have a method as

```
Form.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
Thread tr1 =
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        List<Musteri> list = null;
        IEnumerable<Musteri> result = from Musteri m in Db4OService.Database
                                      where (
                                                m.servisAdi.Contains(text) ||
                                                m.il.Contains(text))
                                      select m;
       list = result.ToList<Musteri>();


        DataGridView dataGridView = ((DataGridView)sayfa.Controls.Find("dataGridView1", false)[0]);
        DataTable dt = ListToDataTable(list);
        try
        {
            dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridView.Refresh();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
                Console.Write(e);

        } 

    });
tr1.Start();
```

This method calls for every time from a textChanged method of textBox . So I want to make it smooth while typing. When I do all stuff in one thread  I have to wait the search method be finished to type another letter. My approach does not work :( Any help welcome. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to separate the Work and do it by another Thread using the [BackgroundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)  this will free help the Textbox to stay un-freeze  while the work is getting done in background

Answer (score 0):

Not trying to pick up on your English here, but it is not very clear whether the code you have in your post is called on a TextChangedEvent or the code generates a TextChangeEvent. Also, does that code work albeit with jerky typing? I would expect the code to have problems.

1. I will make the assumption that the provided code is invoked on your TextChangedEvent, which looks up data from database and populates the Grid.
2. I see that you are trying to update your Grid from the non GUI thread. First off, it is a bad idea to update GUI from non GUI thread.
3. From what I understand of what you want to do, it would be a good idea to actually make this thread a trackable variable, so when a user types in some text, and if your search has still not returned, you might want to stop your DB lookup, as the user might have typed some more. Bottom line is that the user typing might change your search criteria and display result, so you should be able to cancel your searching and grid update, else you are simply wasting resources searching for something that the user is no longer interested in.

Below is how I would code that:

```
bool searching = false;
object searchThreadLock = new object();
Thread searchThread = null;

void TextChangedEvent() {
    lock (searchThreadLock) {
        if (searching && searchThread != null && searchThread.IsAlive)
            searchThread.Abort();

        lookupForData();
    }
}

void lookupForData() {
    searchThread = new Thread( () => {
        // Your code to retrieve relevant data from DB based on your TextChangedEvent goes here
        searching = true;
        try {
            List<Musteri> list = null;
            IEnumerable<Musteri> result = 
                from Musteri m in Db4OService.Database
                    where (
                        m.servisAdi.Contains(text) ||
                        m.il.Contains(text))
                    select m;
            list = result.ToList<Musteri>();
            DataTable dt = ListToDataTable(list);
            updateGrid(dt);
        } catch (ThreadAbortException ex) {
        } finally {
            searching = false;
        }
    } );
    searchThread.start();
}

void updateGrid(DataTable dt) {
    DataGridView dataGridView = ((DataGridView)sayfa.Controls.Find("dataGridView1", false)[0]);
    if (dataGridView.InvokeRequired) {
        dataGridView.BeginInvoke(new Action<DataTable>(updatdeGrid), dt);
        return;
    }

    // Your code to update the grid goes here
    dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
    dataGridView.Refresh();
}
```

PS: Note that Thread.Abort is typically a bad idea, and it should be substituted by your app specific logic to stop the DB searching. I have put that in place as I am not sure how to stop your LINQ query correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Form.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
```

This is bad, learn not to use it. Never ever never ever never. Read about invoking.